# Can I compare daily averages using a T test?

Tags: time-series, t-test, mean, intervention-analysis

Pretend you had a sales group that was required to perform a bunch of administrative work for every prospect they contacted. E.g., entering the prospect's contact info into a CRM, researching the prospect's business, etc. So you decide to hire support staff to do this work for the sales team so that the sales team can spend more time selling (e.g., making calls, participating in meetings, whatever). You might do this if you thought it would lead to more opportunities being created and ultimately won.

I am curious whether you can use a simple t test to validate whether this type of change worked or not. For example, compare the average number of proposals the sales person sent out before you hired the support staff vs. after you hired the support staff? If not, how would you (in)validate the impact?

Comment: If I understand correctly, based on the sentence `compare the average number of proposals the sales person sent out before you hired the support staff vs. after you hired the support staff`, this sounds like a paired t-test.